# Ruby on Rails, find by two conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I am trying to find all values of a given model by a combination of two fields.

I have the following model:

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "clicks_given"
    t.integer  "clicks_received"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

and I have defined this method for the model:

```
  def credits
    credits = self.clicks_given - self.clicks_received
  end
```

I am trying to find all users above a given credits:

```
  @users = User.find(:all, :conditions => { "credits >= ?", -5 })
```

and:

```
  @users = User.find(:all, :conditions => { "clicks_given - clicks_received >= ?", -5 })
```

Fail. What should is the correct statement to to find the right users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the condition as an array instead of a hash:

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => [ "clicks_given - clicks_received >= ?", -5 ])
```

The first version will not work since "credits" is not a database column.

EDIT:

Or in Rails 3 syntax, with your order:

```
@users = User.where("clicks_given - clicks_received >= ?", 5).order("clicks_given - clicks_received")
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still very new to RoR, and I was unaware of the difference between [] for arrays and {} for hashes. Thanks

Comment: In that case, Rails guides are your best friend: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html :)

Comment: THank you, I go there some times, but most of the times I don't know what I m looking for so I end up asking. :)

Comment: Could you please confirm that this will order the elements by the "credits"? `:order => ["clicks_given - clicks_received DESC"]`

Comment: Yes it should, but you don't need to pass the argument for order as an array. A simple string will do: :order => "clicks...."

Comment: I added the Rails 3 way to do it, in case you're using that version.

Comment: I am, and I was getting confused with find and where. The guides say where and order, but most examples I see use find.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't directly use -5 in condition like this:

```
 @users = User.find(:all, 
                    :conditions =>"clicks_given-clicks_received>=-5")
```

and if you have a variable in place of -5 then you can write something like this:

```
@users = User.find(:all, 
                   :conditions => ["clicks_given-clicks_received >= ?",-5])
```

Comment: Because it's likely that -5 will be replaced by a variable in anything but example code.