# rails - how to subtract one query from another?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to do something like this:

```
puts Room.find(1,2,3) - Room.find(1,2)
```

so that it does `Room.find(3)` and returns that SQL record only instead of the 3 records that `Room.find(1,2,3)` gives me

Comment: I just tried it, it works ... you end up with a collection containing your ActiveRecord object (Room number 3 here). It would be a lot more efficient to substract two tabs containing desired IDs though

Comment: See the answer given in [this question][1],  I'm sure it can help you out further.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842623/ruby-on-rails-find-by-two-conditions

Comment: RAILS-4 AND RAILS-5 answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48934508/1536309

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will be much more efficient:

```
first_id_list = [1, 2, 3]
second_id_list = [1, 2]
Room.find(first_id_list - second_id_list)
```

That way, you *only* search for the id's that you really want to be in your query, instead of fetching unwanted rows and then instantiating a bunch of Room objects that you then promptly ignore but Ruby still has to garbage collect.

Answer (score 2):

As  Anthony Alberto pointed out in the comment. This works. Only case this won't work is when you find just one instance of room. For example `Room.find(1)` will return an object of class `Room`, rather than an Array. Therefore you won't be able to use the binary operator `-` on this Speak object. To avoid this from happening, use `to_a` method.

```
Array.wrap(Room.find(1,2,3)) - Array.wrap(Room.find(1))
=> Room.find(2,3)
```

Comment: This gave me: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_a' for #<Room:0x959bba0>`

Comment: Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: Anyways, you can try this as well. `Room.find(1,2,3) - [Room.find(1)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just SQL so that you're not wasting memory!

```
rooms = Room.where(id: [1,2,3])
            .where.not(id: [1,2])
```

OR

```
rooms = Room.where("id IN (?) AND id NOT IN (?)",[1,2,3], [1,2])
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if I leave out the `puts`...

```
1.9.3-p327 :029 > puts Link.find(1,2,3) - Room.find(1,2)
Room Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `rooms` WHERE `rooms`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3)
Link Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `rooms` WHERE `rooms` id` IN (1, 2)
#<Room:0x95bf6a4>
 => nil
```

vs.

```
1.9.3-p327 :026 > Link.find(1,2,3) - Link.find(1,2)
  Room Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `rooms`.* FROM `rooms` WHERE `rooms`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3)
  Room Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `rooms`.* FROM `rooms` WHERE `rooms`.`id` IN (1, 2)
 => [#<Room id: 3, url_address: "http://www.linux.org", alt_text: "Linux", group_id: 3, position: 347, created_at: "2010-10-26 14:41:05", updated_at: "2010-10-26 14:41:05", version_number: "", content_date: nil>] 
1.9.3-p327 :027 > puts Room.find(1,2)
  Room Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `rooms`.* FROM `rooms` WHERE `rooms`.`id` IN (1, 2)
#<Room:0x9724094>
#<Room:0x9723ea0>
 => nil
```

Comment: I am confused as to what your notion of what's working and what's not working. The first one did what puts was suppose to do which is to print Room object and memory location. Anyways, what's Link class doing here?